# How can I convert a number in to standard prefixes?

Tags: python

I wanted to convert a float `0.002116` in to `2.116m(milli)`. I saw libraries that converts float `125510.92808470126` into `125.51K` but outputs `0` with the float value given above.

I tried [numerize python](https://pypi.org/project/numerize/) library so far.

Comment: How is `0.002116` equivalent `2.116m` (million)?

Comment: @OmariCelestine it is in millis (1e-3) not in million.

Comment: What unit is that?

Comment: 1 milli unit = 0.001 unit

Comment: And would that be the only unit for values less than 1?

Comment: I used [this](http://www.csgnetwork.com/converttable.html) link as reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work, change as you like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

pfx_up = [(1e3, 'kilo'), (1e6, 'mega'), (1e9, 'giga'), (1e12, 'tera')]

pfx_down = [(0.001, 'milli'), (1e-6, 'micro'), (1e-9, 'nano'), (1e-12, 'pico'), (1e-15, 'femto')]

def make_prefix( num ) :
    result = str(num)
    if num > 1 :
        for p in pfx_up :
            if num > p[0]*10 :
                result = '%.2f %s' % (num / p[0], p[1])
    else :
        for p in pfx_down :
            if num < p[0]*100 :
                result = '%.2f %s' % (num / p[0], p[1])

    return result

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    print make_prefix(0.01234)
    print make_prefix(1234342)
    print make_prefix(12343464356)
    print make_prefix(0.00001234)
    print make_prefix(0.0000001234)
'''
outputs:
12.34 milli
1234.34 kilo
12.34 giga
12.34 micro
0.12 micro
'''
```

Comment: @KlienMenard sorry, missed `pico`, fixed now =)